# Calling DoEvents in Application.Idle

Tags: .net, asynchronous, python-idle, doevents

I stay away from Application.DoEvents, since there is the issue of re-entrancy and there is always another way to avoid holding up the UI. I've long prefered to do background work in the Application.Idle event as a simple alternative to multi-threading. But, for long-running tasks, is it acceptable to run operations in Application.Idle with a DoEvents loop?

```
class LongRunningTask : IDisposable {

    public LongRunningTask(IEnumerable<Tidbit> listOfDataToBeProcessed) {
       Application.Idle += OnIdle;
    
        foreach(Tidbit t in listofDataToBeProcessed) {
            tidbits.Enqueue(t);
        }
    }
    
    // Small pieces of data to process
    Queue<Tidbit> tidbits = new Queue<Tidbit>();
    
    void OnIdle(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        while(tidbits.Count > 0) {
            var tidbit = tasks.Dequeue();
            tidbit.Process();
            // Process any messages that have queued up
            // while the data was being processed
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
    }
    
    public void Dispose() {
        Application.Idle -= OnIdle;
    }
}
```

The logic here is that in the Application.Idle event, where we call DoEvents, there are no messages queued, so we should not be able to re-enter code. Each tidbit would be processed quickly enough that it should not hold up the message queue (or UI) significantly.

So, is there any harm or drawback to this approach? Namely, is it safe to call DoEvents in the Idle event? I do know that [C# 5 will have a feature to address this sort of situation](https://web.archive.org/web/20151204230821/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/28/asynchrony-in-c-5-part-one.aspx), but for those of us who aren't using C# 5 (which is most of us at the moment), and out of general curiosity, is this a good plan? Or is there a simpler alternative to process messages during a long-running operation without resorting to multi-threading?

Please don't think that I imagine this to be a magic bullet. I know that it comes with *the same pitfalls as any asynchronous approach*. I am aware that one must still be able to keep his application in a consistent state. And I *am* aware that there are multithreaded solutions. I am avoiding those. Why? Because multi-threading is more complicated. I don't think that that's impractical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing here looks a lot like [Cooperative multitasking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_multitasking). It's an interesting idea but I would say that you should really use multi threading for something like this. .NET has a lot of helper systems like `Task.Factory.StartNew()` and the TPL libraries that really make it easy.

I would advise against it.

To be clear though: I do not have a clear reason against it. As with a lot of areas concerning programming: if it works, it works. However, you are mixing things together that should not be mixed together, specifically background tasks and UI tasks. I believe that when you separate the background tasks and start go get your hands dirty with multi threading, thread pools, background tasks and TPL, you'll quickly see that it does work and makes life easier in the long run.

Comment: Well, look at the link I've included in the question. The big thing in C# 5 is cooperative multitasking, on the UI thread! The idea is to execute parts of each task quickly enough to avoid hanging up the message pump. And we all perform some kind of operation on the UI thread that ideally would be considered background work.

Comment: No, that is something different entirely. What they have done is create systems that automatically rewrites synchronous (line by line) code to asynchronous code. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult.aspx for more information on the IAsyncResult interface wich is *a* mechanism for doing asynchronous programming. In short: asynchronous programming is a way to put work on e.g. a different thread and synchronize the results of that thread with e.g. the UI thread.

Comment: It's true that the async feature does turn line-by-line code to asynchronous code, but it is not multithreaded. The fact that I'm not transforming code doesn't mean that I'm doing something different, though. Both approaches enqueue tasks to be done later, mine via a queue of atomic tidbits and the idle event, Microsoft's via state machines that resume execution via the message queue/loop. But that's all beside the point. What I'm after is a simpler solution for those instances where multithreading isn't worth the effort (as a matter of opinion or preference).

Comment: OK, I understand. To be hones, I don't think I have anything to add beyond the answer above.

Comment: It may be that my distaste for multithreading is just the result of little experience in that arena. Does it seem that I'm overestimating the value of not having to worry about two threads accessing the same memory/object at the same time? That seems to be the only real obstacle I'm side-stepping, but it also seems to take a lot of effort when sometimes the benefit seems questionable.

Comment: Yes, I understand. What I think is that you may just have to bite the bullet and, when you do, you'll see that it's not that big of a problem as you though. E.g. concerning threads accessing data: if you create a kind of work package where you put all the data the thread is going to access in (if it's e.g. processing data), hand that over to the thread and then get that back at the end of the processing job, you don't have any problems at all. It is a different kind of programming but in the long run, it's a lot cleaner and yes, easier.